# Get index of array which contains/include string value in javascript/Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

My question is how to get index of array which contains/includes string value. See my code below to get the result I want.

This is simple code to get index of array:

```
var myarr = ["I", "like", "turtles"];
var arraycontainsturtles = (myarr.indexOf("turtles"));
console.log(arraycontainsturtles) // the result will be 2
```

I want to get the index result with a code sample below:

```
var myarr = ["I", "like", "turtles"];
var arraycontainsturtles = (myarr.indexOf("turt"));
console.log(arraycontainsturtles) // i want the result will be 2 with the contains string just the 'turt' only.
```

How to get the index with a contains string value like at the sample number 2? The real result of the number 2 will be `-1`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `findIndex` instead of `indexOf`, as you can provide a function.

```js
var myarr = ["I", "like", "turtles"];
var arraycontainsturtles = (myarr.findIndex(function(item){
    return item.indexOf("turt")!==-1;
}));
console.log(arraycontainsturtles) // 2
```

Comment: thanks it solved. another answer is good. but this code is very simple .. 
thanks @Kevin Drost

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myarr = ["I", "like", "turtles"];
    var arraycontainsturtles = -1;
    for(i=0;i<myarr.length;i++){
    if((myarr[i].indexOf("turt")) != -1){
           arraycontainsturtles = i;
    }
    }
    console.log(arraycontainsturtles)
```

Comment: It works in this case, but does not return the first index when `"turt"` exists more than once in the array

Comment: @KevinDrost, there is no proper req in question to get only first index. off you can use break to come out the loop ,after find out the index.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what your looking for

```js
var myarr = ["I", "like", "turtles"];
var search = "turt";
var arraycontainsturtles = myarr.reverse().reduce((a, v, i) => v.indexOf(search) != -1 ? Math.abs(i - myarr.length + 1) : a, -1);
console.log(arraycontainsturtles)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myarr = ["I", "like", "turtles"];
var arraycontainsturtles = function(arr, str){
  let filter = -1;
  filter = arr.findIndex((e) => {
     return e.indexOf(str) > -1 ; 
  });
 return filter;
}

console.log(arraycontainsturtles(myarr, "turt"))
```